# SYSENTER/SYSEXIT vs INT 0x80

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

Old linux versions use "int 0x80" instruction to implement system call, the later versions use "SYSENTER/SYSEXIT" instructions to do so.

After transfer to ring 0 via "int 0x80", cpu is in interrupt context and interrupt is disabled. But "SYSENTER/SYSEXIT" will not produce "interrupt context" and interrupt is not disabled.

Will this difference cause problems for system call?

Comment: I suspect the fact that Linux continues to run well and reliably probably indicates that the switch didn't cause any problems (or that any problems that did show up have been handled)...

Answer (score 6):

Whoever gets the call is clear what is going on, and has to cope. Remember that interrupts are the way to alert  the system that something requiring urgent attention has come up, it better be handled ASAP. Disabling interrupts degrades performance, as event handling gets delayed. The new instructions SYSENTER/SYSEXIT instructions were added by intel not too long ago to offer faster/simpler system call handling, Linux started using them almost immediately.

For a bit of historical perspective, computers used to have one CPU. Disabling interrupts on them was a (brutal) way of ensuring mutual exclusion: As long as interrupts were disabled, *nothing* (with little exception) could interfere, because nothing else could be happening. So forcing an interrupt was a simple way to get system calls done, with the extra benefit of ensuring no interference. With multi-CPU machines (even cell phones!), disabling interrupts on the CPU getting to handle the call buys very little, others can go ahead and trample on your work. Disabling interrupts system-wide is costly to do, and just halting the whole system just to ensure mutual exclusion is madness. Current versions of Linux use sophisticated synchronization techniques to avoid such heavy-handed methods if at all possible. So the protection against interrupts isn't so important anymore.

Comment: But as I know, linux will do something critical just when enter an interrupt handler atomically(interrupt is disabled), and the reset work are scheduled via software interrupt known as "behind-half machinasim" which doesn't need to be atomical code.

Comment: "not too long ago" -- Pentium II shipped in 1997 and was the first Intel CPU to support SYSENTER. No current x86 or x64 system lacks those instructions,